# How to decrypt a file that encrypted with rc4 using Python?

Tags: python, encryption, rc4-cipher

I got a file that encrypted with rc4 key.

I got that key and want to decrypt it with a python script.

How can I do this?

Comment: Related: here is a useful way to RC4 encrypt with Python: https://github.com/bozhu/RC4-Python/blob/master/rc4.py

Answer (score 5):

Found the following after a 3 second Google search: http://www.emoticode.net/python/python-implementation-of-rc4-algorithm.html

Modified it thusly:

```
import base64

data = base64.b64decode("<encrypted file contents>")
key = "<rc4 key>"

S = range(256)
j = 0
out = []

#KSA Phase
for i in range(256):
    j = (j + S[i] + ord( key[i % len(key)] )) % 256
    S[i] , S[j] = S[j] , S[i]

#PRGA Phase
i = j = 0
for char in data:
    i = ( i + 1 ) % 256
    j = ( j + S[i] ) % 256
    S[i] , S[j] = S[j] , S[i]
    out.append(chr(ord(char) ^ S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256]))

print ''.join(out)
```

Not sure if this will work, as you did not give us any data to work with.. next time please post an example of the data, the code you have already tried, and what errors you are getting.

---

#### Edit -- Working with files

```
import base64

with open("/path/to/file.txt", "r") as encrypted_file:
    data = base64.b64decode(encrypted_file.read())
key = "<rc4 key>"

S = range(256)
j = 0
out = []

#KSA Phase
for i in range(256):
    j = (j + S[i] + ord( key[i % len(key)] )) % 256
    S[i] , S[j] = S[j] , S[i]

#PRGA Phase
i = j = 0
for char in data:
    i = ( i + 1 ) % 256
    j = ( j + S[i] ) % 256
    S[i] , S[j] = S[j] , S[i]
    out.append(chr(ord(char) ^ S[(S[i] + S[j]) % 256]))

decrypted_text = ''.join(out)
with open('decrypted.txt', 'w') as decrypted_file:
    decrypted_file.write(decrypted_text)
```

Comment: Yeah I found it too.. But there is a problem with that script to read a file and decrypt it..

Comment: Python can read the contents of the file, if you tell it. `with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r') as encrypted_file:`

Comment: I got a problem with the read file.. The file type is DAT file and not txt.
I got the error below:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decrypt.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = base64.b64decode(encrypted_file.read())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\base64.py", line 76, in b64decode
    raise TypeError(msg)
TypeError: Incorrect padding

Comment: Ah, sounds like you have a corrupted file. If you have access to openssl (should be installed by default on your linux machine) try using that instead of Python. It is more intelligent with Base64. Here is an example decode command: `openssl enc -d -base64 -in <copy_paste_data_here> -out binary_data`

Comment: Rolling your own encryption is a bad idea. The PyCryptodome answer is the correct path.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own

Answer (score 4):

PyCryptodome does it nowadays: https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/cipher/arc4.html

```
from Crypto.Cipher import ARC4
key = b'Very long and confidential key'
cipher = ARC4.new(key)
msg = cipher.encrypt(b'Open the pod bay doors, HAL')
```